# Функции не видят глобальную переменную

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
browser: webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver
def start():
    chromedriver = config.driver # путь к драйверу chrome
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.binary_location = config.binary_location
    options.add_argument('disable-gpu') # для отключения GPU в использовании драйверного браузера
    options.add_argument("window-size=800,600")
    options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=options)
    os.system('cls')
    print(type(browser))

def auth(cookie_list):
    i = 0
    browser.delete_all_cookies()
    browser.get('https://www.youtube.com/')

    for cookie in cookie_list:
        try:
            browser.add_cookie(json.loads(converter.normalized_cook(cookie)))
            i = i + 1
        except UnableToSetCookieException:
            continue
    if config.beta:
        print('[google cookies]:', i)
    browser.refresh()
```

переменную **browser** функция **auth** не видит

Comment: В `start` добавьте `global browser`, т.к. там делается присваивание в `browser`, иначе будет создана новая переменная, чья область жизни будет ограничение функцией

Comment: в начале обоих функций напишите `global browser`

Comment: @gil9red а как присвоить ей тип? 'webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver'

Comment: Кому? Это будет та же переменная объявленная вне тех функций, просто вы говорите интерпретатору, что в функции нужно ее менять, а не создавать новую внутри функции

Answer (score 2):

Решил с помощью создания нового файла

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser: webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver
```

и в функциях использую имяфайла.browser